# Spring Cloud Stream for Kafka with consumer/producer API exactly once semantics with transaction-id-prefix is not working as expected

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, spring-cloud-stream

I have scenario where am seeing different behavior. Like total of 3 different services

- First service will listen from Solace queue and produce it to kafka
  topic-1 (where transaction are enabled)
- Second Service will listen from above kafka topic-1 and write it to another kafka topic-2 (where we have no manual commits, transactions
  enabled to produce to other topic, auto commit offset as false &
  isolation.level is set to read_commited) 
  ago     Delete
- Third Service will listen from kafka topic-2 and write it back to Solace queue (where we have no manual commits, auto commit offset as
  false & isolation.level is set to read_commited).

Now the issue after I enabled transaction and isolation level at the second service am not able to read any messages, if I disabled the transaction in second service am able to read all the messages.

- Can we have transactions enabled & isolation level in one single service
- How it works if my service is just a producer or consumer (how EoS guaranteed for these services)

Edited:
Below is how my yml looks

```
 - kafka:
   - binder:
     - transaction:
         - transaction-id-prefix:
       - brokers: 
         - configuration: 
               all my consumer properties (ssl, sasl)
```

Updated (yml with spring cloud):

```
spring: 
  cloud.stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          destination: test_input
          content-type: application/json
          group: test_group
        output:
          destination: test_output
          content-type: application/json
      kafka.binder: 
          configuration: 
            isolation.level: read_committed
            security.protocol: SASL_SSL
            sasl.mechanism: GSSAPI
            sasl.kerberos.service.name: kafka
            ssl.truststore.location: jks
            ssl.truststore.password: 
            ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm: null            
          brokers: broker1:9092,broker2:9092,broker3:9092
          auto-create-topics: false
          transaction:
            transaction-id-prefix: trans-2
            producer:
              configuration:
                retries: 2000
                acks: all
                security.protocol: SASL_SSL
                sasl.mechanism: GSSAPI
                sasl.kerberos.service.name: kafka
                ssl.truststore.location: jks
                ssl.truststore.password: 
                ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm: null
```

Updated (yml with spring kafka):

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: broker1:9092,broker2:9092,broker3:9092
    consumer:
      properties:
        isolation.level: read_committed
        ssl.truststore.location: truststore.jks
        ssl.truststore.password: 
        security.protocol: SASL_SSL
        sasl.mechanism: GSSAPI
        sasl.kerberos.service.name: kafka
    producer:
      transaction-id-prefix: trans-2
      retries: 2000
      acks: all
      properties:
        ssl.truststore.location: truststore.jks
        ssl.truststore.password: 
        security.protocol: SASL_SSL
        sasl.mechanism: GSSAPI
        sasl.kerberos.service.name: kafka
    admin:
      properties:
        ssl.truststore.location: truststore.jks
        ssl.truststore.password: 
        security.protocol: SASL_SSL
        sasl.mechanism: GSSAPI
        sasl.kerberos.service.name: kafka
```

Updated with dynamic destination

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform operation after producer has been closed
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.throwIfProducerClosed(KafkaProducer.java:810) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:819) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:803) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.send(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:423) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:351) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:209) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(KafkaProducerMessageHandler.java:382) ~[spring-integration-kafka-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:123) [spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:169) [spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
```

tried both the approaches for dynamic destination resolver issue:
[dynamic destination resolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#dynamicdestination)

Comment: It should work fine; I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me; these are all in the same app, but that won't make a difference...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Channels.class)
public class So55419549Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So55419549Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow service1(MessageChannel out1) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(() -> "foo", e -> e
                    .poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(Duration.ofSeconds(5))))
                .log(Level.INFO, m -> "s1 " + m.getPayload())
                .channel(out1)
                .get();
    }

    @StreamListener("in2")
    @SendTo("out2")
    public String service2(String in) {
        System.out.println("s2 " + in);
        return in.toUpperCase();
    }

    @StreamListener("in3")
    public void service3(String in) {
        System.out.println("s3 " + in);
    }

}

interface Channels {

    @Output
    MessageChannel out1();

    @Input
    MessageChannel in2();

    @Output
    MessageChannel out2();

    @Input
    MessageChannel in3();

}
```

and

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        out1:
          destination: topic1
        in2:
          group: s2
          destination: topic1
        out2:
          destination: topic2
        in3:
          group: s3
          destination: topic2
      kafka:
        binder:
          transaction:
            transaction-id-prefix: tx
        bindings:
          in2:
            consumer:
              configuration:
                isolation:
                  level: read_committed
          in3:
            consumer:
              configuration:
                isolation:
                  level: read_committed
  kafka:
    producer:
      # needed again here so boot declares a TM for us
      transaction-id-prefix: tx
      retries: 10
      acks: all
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.kafka.transaction: debug
```

and

```
2019-03-29 12:57:08.345  INFO 75700 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   
    : s1 foo
2019-03-29 12:57:08.353 DEBUG 75700 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.k.t.KafkaTransactionManager          : Creating new transaction with name [null]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2019-03-29 12:57:08.353 DEBUG 75700 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.k.t.KafkaTransactionManager          : Created Kafka transaction on producer [CloseSafeProducer [delegate=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@6790c874, txId=txs2.topic1.0]]
s2 foo
2019-03-29 12:57:08.357 DEBUG 75700 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.k.t.KafkaTransactionManager          : Creating new transaction with name [null]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2019-03-29 12:57:08.358 DEBUG 75700 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.k.t.KafkaTransactionManager          : Created Kafka transaction on producer [CloseSafeProducer [delegate=org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@820ef3d, txId=txs3.topic2.0]]
s3 FOO
```

**EDIT**

The binder doesn't enable transaction synchronization on the transaction manager. As a workaround, add

```
TransactionSynchronizationManager.setActualTransactionActive(true);
```

to your `@StreamListener`.

I opened [a bug](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/623) against the binder.

Comment: when I tried the same configuration am getting some error (Error during transactional operation; producer removed from cache; possible cause: broker restarted during transaction) and my listener (who supposed to listen committed messages from his previous service)  is not able  to listen any messages. After some time heartbeat is failing and it's going for rebalancing. Below is how my yml looks 
      kafka:
        binder:
          transaction:
            transaction-id-prefix:
         brokers: 
         configuration: 
            all my consumer properties (ssl, sasl)

Comment: Don't put yaml in comments; edit the question instead. I don't know what else I can say; you must have something wrong; it worked fine on the first attempt for me.

Comment: As I said, I can't help more with the information you have provided; my properly configured application works perfectly fine, so you must have something else wrong. Unless you can post a simplified version of your app (complete), that exhibits the behavior you see someplace, I can't help further.

Comment: edited the question with updated .yml's. When I tried with spring cloud am not able to have both configuration (under kafka.binder) and transaction (kafka.binder). It's trying to create multiple producer thread but transaction suffix for each producer thread is not the sequence number (for initial two threads am getting sequence number 0,1 and for third thread am seeing transaction as appended with prefix + group name + topic name + seq num). and when I tried same config without spring cloud it's working fine as expected. If there's any wrong config i have done please correct me .

Comment: Yes; there is something wrong, the producer is not participating in the global transaction. Investigating...

Comment: Thanks for the work around Gary, I just tested and it's working fine with my scenario also. Thanks again

Comment: Having another issue after I updated my stream listener with the workaround. With in the same listener if am using @SentTo and return the message to desired destination it's working fine , but if am using dynamic destination resolver am getting the exception. Updated the above question with exception & code

Comment: This is unrelated; the admins here don't like extended commentary on questions/answers; close this one out and ask a new question showing your current code/configuration.

Comment: This issue is resolved in spring-integration-kafka 3.1.2, which is now in maven central,

Comment: Thanks Gary, will check it out