# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka consumer/producer API exactly once semantics (transactional)

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, spring-cloud-stream

Spring Cloud Stream Kafka with transaction enabled and dynamic destination is having issues. I have two different services

- First service will listen from Solace queue and produce it to kafka topic-1 (where transaction are enabled)
- Second Service will listen from above kafka topic-1 and write it to another kafka topic-2 (where we have no manual commits, transactions enabled to produce to other topic, auto commit offset as false & isolation.level is set to read_commited) and we will identifying the topicnames dynamically so we are using dynamic destination resolver

Now am having an issue with the second service if am just running the service as @StreamListener & @SendTo it's working fine as expected. But when I started using dynamic destination am getting the below issue:
dynamic destination

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform operation after producer has been closed
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.throwIfProducerClosed(KafkaProducer.java:810) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:819) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:803) ~[kafka-clients-2.0.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.send(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:423) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:351) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:209) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(KafkaProducerMessageHandler.java:382) ~[spring-integration-kafka-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:123) [spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:169) [spring-integration-core-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
```

tried both the approaches for dynamic destination resolver:
[dynamic destination resolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#dynamicdestination)

yml for spring cloud kafka:

```
spring: 
  cloud.stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          destination: test_input
          content-type: application/json
          group: test_group
        output:
          destination: test_output
          content-type: application/json
      kafka.binder: 
          configuration: 
            isolation.level: read_committed
            security.protocol: SASL_SSL
            sasl.mechanism: GSSAPI
            sasl.kerberos.service.name: kafka
            ssl.truststore.location: jks
            ssl.truststore.password: 
            ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm: null            
          brokers: broker1:9092,broker2:9092,broker3:9092
          auto-create-topics: false
          transaction:
            transaction-id-prefix: trans-2
            producer:
              configuration:
                retries: 2000
                acks: all
                security.protocol: SASL_SSL
                sasl.mechanism: GSSAPI
                sasl.kerberos.service.name: kafka
                ssl.truststore.location: jks
                ssl.truststore.password: 
                ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm: null
```

Here's background of this question 
[Spring Cloud Stream for Kafka with consumer/producer API exactly once semantics with transaction-id-prefix is not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55419549/spring-cloud-stream-for-kafka-with-consumer-producer-api-exactly-once-semantics)

Updated the code:

```
    @Autowired
    private BinderAwareChannelResolver resolver;

    @StreamListener(target = Processor.INPUT)
    public void consumer(@Payload Object inMessage, @Headers Map headers) {
        String topicName = null;
        String itemType = null;
        try {
            TransactionSynchronizationManager.setActualTransactionActive(true);     
            itemType = msgService.itemTypeExtract((String) inMessage);          
            topicName = msgService.getTopicName(itemType, (String) inMessage);      

            Map<String, Object> headersMap = new HashMap<>();
            headersMap.put(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

            resolver.resolveDestination("destination_topic")
                    .send(MessageBuilder.createMessage(inMessage, new MessageHeaders(headersMap)), 10000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("error " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to show the code.

Comment: Updated question with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bug in the binder; I opened [an issue to get it fixed](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/626).

Comment: Thanks for checking Gary